# Extracting and changing just one field in xml in mule esb

Tags: xml, mule

Here is my xml.
I just need to change only one field with this condn : if field.id == x then event.id = y. Apart from that everythingelse is same.

```
 <field>
      <field id="XXXX_GATE" />     
      <field gapptNbr="608" />
      <field gapptNbr="609" />
      <field-change id="tvdtlsNextStageId" new-value="yard" prev-value="main_in" />
    </field>
```

How can I achieve this with a minimal effort,
Any help is appreciated.
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solutions I have used:

XML to DOM -> Return Class: org.dom4j.Document

```
 event =  message.payload.getRootElement().selectSingleNode('//host-outbound-message/event');
 field =  message.payload.getRootElement().selectSingleNode('//host-outbound-message/event/field-changes/field');
if ( fieldAttribute.getValue() == 'Xray'  ){
  eventAttribute.setValue("XRAY_GATE_IN");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Groovy component with the following script as example:

```
def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(payload)
if (root.event.'field-changes'.field.@id == 'VICT_GATE') {
  root.event.@id = "BUS_GATE_IN";
}

return groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(root)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XPath /XQuery support in MuleESB to read in the values, evaluate the expression and set the values based on the condition. See these links for details -

http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/mule-3-6-xml-xpath-xslt-xquery3/
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/xpath

So, this could be one way of doing it -
1. Read in the attribute value based on the xpath expression field.id and event.id and assign to variables, say f and e

2. Compare the field.id to the required value, say r
3. Based on the value of the above expression, assign a new value say n to e